# Checking content with inArray to add class

Tags: jquery

So jQuery "inArray" is a new beast for me so am a little unsure how this'll work. 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

I have a div with this content "0 CHECKOUT NOW".

I would like to check for when the 0 changes to another number, if it does change add a class of "active" to the containing div.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="search-again-panel-top">
    <a class="checkout-now" href="#">
    0 CHECKOUT NOW
    </a>
</div>
```

This was what I tried to do:

```
$('.search-again-panel-top .checkout-now').filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text('0');
        return $.inArray(text, this) = -1;
    }).addClass('active');
```

Comment: What does `inArray` have to do with this?

Comment: How does the text change? Isn't it easier to do that check in the code that causes the text to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var checkElement = $('.search-again-panel-top .checkout-now')
var parts = $(checkElement).html().split(" ");
if (jQuery.inArray("0", parts) == -1) {
//do nothing
} else {
//has changed
$(checkElement).addClass("active");
}
```

The jquery.inArray function basically passes the item your searching for as the first parameter, and the actual array your checking in as the second parameter and checks if it exists. If the item is found in the array it will return the character position in the string it was found in. If it is not found, it will return -1

Comment: Tried this one, but no joy! How would I make it specific to the checkout-now anchor?

Comment: Check the edit. I have replaced $(this) with checkElement defined as the .checkout-now anchor. No need to include your filter() function. just this directly should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry I also had the if statement around the wrong way. Replace > with == as seen in edit. http://jsfiddle.net/wsLHg/ the linked jsfiddle works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text instead of getting it, you shouldn't use a parameter when getting the text. To check for a text in an array you need to use `split` to get an array, and you should look for `'0'`, not `this`, and check if the result is not equal to -1.

```
var text = $(this).text();
text = text.split (' ');
return $.inArray('0', text) != -1;
```

Comment: Thanks but this failed for me...

 $('.search-again-panel-top .checkout-now').filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.split (' ');
  return $.inArray('0', text) != -1;
    }).addClass('active');